# Some version of the Annulus theorem

Tags: manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

Let A,B,C,D be tame (not wild) n-1-spheres inside the n-sphere S such that $A\cap B = C \cap D = \emptyset$. Let also   $f: A \rightarrow C$ and $g: B \rightarrow D$ be two homeomorphisms. Is there any homeomorphism $h: S \rightarrow S$ that extends f and g?

If it is false, in which dimensions is it true?

Comment: You should correct: $A'=C, B'=D$ and use MathJax consistently. Try to prove that the answer is negative by considering $A=C, B=D$, $f=id$ case.

Comment: You're right. It would imply that any two maps between two spheres are isotopic, which is not true in general. Thanks.

Comment: You now can answer your own question.